# Como posso printar uma string digitada pelo usuário em Assembly 8086?

Tags: assembly, 8086

Estou com dificuldades para conseguir printar uma string que foi posteriormente digitada pelo usuário através do INT 21h/AH 0Ah. Não tenho ideia de como posso fazer para printar a string que foi arquivada em AL.

```
mov ah, 0Ah
int 21h
```

Já tentei utilizar o INT 21h/AH 09h, porém acho que não soube utilizar de maneira correta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma string pode ser lida do teclado por meio das funções / interrupões:

- `0Ah/21h`   : entrada bufferizada
- `03Fh/21h`  : leitura de arquivo ou dispositivo
- `08h/21h`   : leitura caractere a caractere (loop manual)
- `4810h/2Fh` : entrada bufferizada usando DOSKEY (demanda o [DOSKEY TSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSKEY)
  instalado)

Dado o tipo do problema relatado, suponho que você esteja lendo a entrada por meio de buffer `0Ah/21h`.

Para o buffer ser utilizado nessa leitura existem certos requisitos a serem seguidos:

- O primeiro byte dirá qual o tamanho máximo de caracteres a serem
  lidos.
- O segundo byte retornará o número de bytes efetivamente lidos.
- A partir do terceiro byte é que de fato inicia-se a string lida.

Um buffer declarado no seguinte formato não serve:

```
BUFFER db 255 DUP('$')
```

Um bom buffer para leitura de string terá a seguinte forma:

```
BUFFER db 255         ; Número máximo de elemementos a serem lidos.
       db ?           ; Número de elementos lidos retornado pela interrução sem incluir o enter.
STRING db 255 DUP(0)  ; Variável armazenando o texto lido.
```

Posteriormente, de posse da quantidade de caracteres lidos, será feita a substituição do enter `chr(13)` final do buffer pelo terminador de string.

O código abaixo realiza a leitura e impressão de uma string, comentando os procedimentos seguidos.

```
DOSSEG
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK

.DATA
    BUFFER db 255             ; Número máximo de elemementos a serem lidos.
           db ?               ; Número de elementos lidos retornado pela interrução sem incluir o enter.
    STRING db 255 DUP(0)      ; Variável armazenando o texto lido.
    TERMINADOR db 10D,13D,'$'

.CODE
inicio:
    ; Inicializa o segmento de dados.
    mov ax,SEG _DATA
    mov ds,ax

    ; Lê entrada no buffer.
    mov dx,OFFSET BUFFER
    mov ah,0ah
    int 21h

    ; Substitui enter chr(13) por término de string.
    mov si, offset BUFFER + 1 ; Carrega em si o número de elementos lidos.
    mov cl, [si]              ; Armazena em cl o número de elementos lidos.
    mov ch, 0                 ; Zera ch para poder usar cx.
    inc cx                    ; cx passa a armazenar a posição do enter chr(13) final do buffer
    add si, cx                ; si aponta para a posição
    mov al, '$'
    mov [si], al              ; substitui o enter chr(13) pelo terminadore de string '$'

    ; imprime terminador
    mov dx, OFFSET TERMINADOR
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h

    ; imprime string
    mov dx,OFFSET STRING
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h

    mov ah,4ch              ; funcao de termino
    int 21h                 ; interrupcao do DOS
END inicio
```

O código foi testado usando o compilador [MASM 5.00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler) neste [emulador](https://etpi.wordpress.com/2017/03/31/8086-assembler-emulator-for-win-7-x86x64/) com [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/)